# Evil and pain awaits the one who possesses me

Tags: riddle

> - You might be tempted to use me but beware, for being hasty could make you a hypocrite.
> - I sometimes like to hunt. Especially birds. The more the better!
> - Some people like the sound that me and my friends make when we start spinning around.
> - You better make sure I am not within you for that could only make you an evil person or cause you horrible suffering.
> - You might wonder who I am, but know that there is only one answer and that will never change for it is within me.

Who am I?

Comment: Seems like it could be wind, or wind related?

Comment: @KaranAtree no chance I'm gonna say if that is correct or not, but feel free to gather evidences and give it a shot :)

Comment: Words fits with everything but the second clue. Word's could hunt, but why birds?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are a:

> Stone

You might be tempted to use me but beware, for being hasty could make you a hypocrite

> Let he who is without sin cast the first stone (John 8:7, thanks @Rubio!)

I sometimes like to hunt. Especially birds. The more the better!

> Killing two birds with one stone

Some people like the sound that me and my friends make when we start spinning around

> The Rolling Stones are a very popular rock band

You better make sure I am not within you for that could only make you an evil person or cause you horrible suffering

> Evil people have hearts of stone (thanks @oleslaw!), but kidney stones hurt like beejezus (or so I hear)

You might wonder who I am, but know that there is only one answer and that will never change for it is within me

> The word 'one' is within 'stone' (well played, OP!)

Comment: Evil person has a heart of stone.

Comment: hypocrite:  John 8:7.   and +1, this has to be it

Comment: @Xenocacia you flatter me more than I deserve. The "one" thing was not intentional haha. The solution is meant to be an expression. Can you find it? Also good job on the glass house one, it fits well, although I had another proverb in mind. Any idea which?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion if there was any. This IS the correct answer. By "the solution" I meant the solution of that hint only. The "solution" for my last hint is the only thing missing from this answer now.

Comment: "and that will never change" -> written in stone?

Comment: @whrrgarbl That is actually very very close. Actually it has pretty much the same meaning so I guess it would be acceptable. I was going for set in *****

Answer (score 1):

Would like to give it a try though not sure if this is anywhere close. :)

Is it -

> Wire

You might be tempted to use me but beware, for being hasty could make you a hypocrite.

> Wire can also mean, ***"a secret recording device hidden worn by a person, especially one that is hidden in their clothes"*** which might be related to being hypocrite.

I sometimes like to hunt. Especially birds. The more the better!

> Birds die due to electrocution caused by Power Lines made up of wires. Mostly during rains.

Some people like the sound that me and my friends make when we start spinning around.

> Skipping rope/wire produces sound during excercing.

You better make sure I am not within you for that could only make you an evil person or cause you horrible suffering.

> This might be a suicide bomber carrying wired bomb.

Answer (score 1):

It is a

> Bullet

You might be tempted to use me but beware, for being hasty could make you a hypocrite.

> Many people see it as the first solution to many problems (let's just kill that person), but if you don't think much before using it, it makes you a hypocrite

I sometimes like to hunt. Especially birds. The more the better!

> Bullets are used in hunting. More birds with one bullet is always better.

Some people like the sound that me and my friends make when we start spinning around.

> When the bullet starts spinning in air after it's shot it makes a distinct sound.

You better make sure I am not within you for that could only make you an evil person or cause you horrible suffering.

> If the bullet is inside someone either that person is evil or is termed evil by media, and it causes horrible suffering to anyone who has a bullet inside.

You might wonder who I am, but know that there is only one answer and that will never change for it is within me.

> Not sure of this one, but lead balls and other projectiles which were use as bullets before are used inside bullets now

Comment: Nice try. But not quite.